# How do I filter specific word from a values

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to filter out the values in x that contains the word 'India'.

```
webpage <- getURL("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019027952/msft-10k_20190630.htm")
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
# parse the tree by tables
x <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table", xmlValue)  
# do some clean up with regular expressions
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
x <- gsub("\t","",x)
x <- sub("^[[:space:]]*(.*?)[[:space:]]*$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
x <- x[!(x %in% c("", "|"))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rvest` which I find simpler for scraping.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019027952/msft-10k_20190630.htm"

url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_text() %>%
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  grep("India", ., value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know where I can read about the accessor notation you are using? The .[[1]] . I have read the [following](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-accessors-explained/) but I would like something a little clearer and perhaps from any official documentation.

Comment: @QHarr The official documentation is at `?Extract` or [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) where it explains difference between various ways to access data namely `[`, `[[` and `$`.